# Intel (R) Dual band wireless-ac 3160 not working on some WiFi's

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

My friend has this wireless card in his laptop (Intel (R) Dual band wireless-ac 3160) and it works fine at his home wifi (or any other), but on the schools wifi it does not.
Anyone who has any clues about why this is happening?